# Achieving better test result with fewer training data - why?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification

I'm currently dealing with a strange data set. I've split it up into a 50% training and 50% test set. I get better test (not training!) accuracy results, when I omit around 30% of the training set, which I find weirdly unintuitive. I've tried different training and test splits, and I can always find a set of around 30% of the training set which worsens the test accuracy.

What does this tells me about the data?
Are the labels sometimes wrong? Do I have too few data in the test set so that it is biased? Or…?

Comment: To make the comparisons fair, I would suggest fixing the test set while comparing the effect of the size of training data. Also, please make sure the number of samples in the test set is sufficient. BTW, how many samples you have in total?

Comment: I use exactly the same fixed test set, and randomly remove data points from the training set, und the accuracy goes up, not down. And the same behavior has been tested for different training/test splits, but when removing random training points the test size stays always the same. And I have 6000 samples in total.